# Migrate a Array into a Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working on an app with `synchronization`. In the app I have stored the data on a sqlite database. But somewhere I have some thinking errors

First i need to migrate an arraylist into a database. In the database i have three columns. For example 
 `| id | name | state |` now i have an arraylist for name. With more or less entrys. Now i want to migrate them into the database, but the column "state" should not be changed. (Unless there are fewer values ​​then the entire column should be cleared).

Second when i have more then two devices connected to the sync service. How can i manage that at the same time the Devices have different changes. When i use the timestamp to find out which is currently the newest database. I will lost on the other Devices the data. Is there any solution to manage this problem?

Comment: those are columns not rows

Comment: @blackbelt You are right ;) I have edit the post.